# Annihilator of extension of scalars vs. the extension the annihilatar

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $A,B$ be commutative rings with 1, $f:A\to B$ a morphism of rings, $M$ an $A$-module, and $M_B=B\otimes_AM$ the extension of scalars.  Then is it the case that $\text{Ann}(M)^e=\text{Ann}(M_B)$?

The forward inclusion is simple, but I can't get the other direction and I also haven't come up with a counterexample.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I suppose you mean: $\DeclareMathOperator\ann{Ann} \ann_A(M)\otimes_A B=  \ann_B(M\otimes_A B)$?

Comment: I don't think so, I mean the extension of the ideal $\text{Ann}(M)$ in $B$.  Or $Bf(\text{Ann}(M))$.

Comment: Maybe what you are saying is true though I will think about it.

Comment: No, it can't be true ‘as is’. The extension of Ann$_A(M)$ is the image of the tensor product in $B$ by the canonical homomorphism. However, if $B$ is a flat $A$-module,this homomorphism is an isomrphism.

Comment: @Bernard I think we also need $M$ finitely generated.

Comment: @user26857: That's what I've just written in my answer:)

Comment: I'm not sure who to give the check mark to, but both of the below answers were very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\mathbb Z$, $B=\mathbb Q$, and $M=\oplus_{n\ge1}\mathbb Z/2^n\mathbb Z$. Then $\operatorname{Ann}_A(M)=(0)$, while $\operatorname{Ann}_B(M_B)=B$ since $M\otimes_AB=0$.

**Remark.** In this example $A\to B$ is flat, but $M$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: It's a fine example!

Answer (score 3):

It is true if $M$ is finitely generated over $A$ and if $B$ is a flat $A$-module (Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, Ch. I: Flat Modules, § 2-10, cor. 2 to prop. 12).

Comment: Okay so I think I found a counterexample with the guidance of that result.  

$A=\mathbb{Z}$, $B=\mathbb{Z}/(2)$, and $M=\mathbb{Q}$.  Then $\text{Ann}(\mathbb{Q})=(0)$ but $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/(2)=0$.

Comment: @xavier17: Fine! You can extend your counter-example to the case of an integral domain $A$ with quotient field $K\,\,$ ($A \neq K$) and $B=A/I$, where $I$ is an ideal of $A$.

Comment: @Bernard I see, thanks!